# Repeater control with IF Else statement always reture true or false in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

I need to show HTML based on the `Container.ItemIndex % 2 ==0` condition

But for me it always return either true or false based on the coding in the code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" OnItemDataBound="rptNews_ItemDataBound">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div style="display:none;"><%# _repeaterIndex = Container.ItemIndex %></div>
      <% if (_repeaterIndex % 2 == 0)  
         {%>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 no-padding newslist-col">
         <div class="blog-item style-3">
            <div class="blog-image">
               <img alt="image" class="img-responsive center-block" src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
            </div>
            <div class="blog-content">
               <div class="text-center">
                  <h5 class="date"><%# getDate(Eval("Date")) %></h5>
                  <h3 class="title-news blog-title newslisttitle"><%# Eval("Heading") %></h3>
                  <a href='<%# getURL(Eval("ID")) %>'><strong> MORE </span></strong></a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <%  }
         else
         { %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 no-padding newslist-col">
         <div class="blog-item style-3">
            <div class="blog-content content-top">
               <div class="text-center">
                  <h5 class="date"><%# Eval("Date") %></h5>
                  <h3 class="title-news blog-title newslisttitle"><%# _repeaterIndex %> <%# Eval("Heading") %></h3>
                  <a href='<%# getURL(Eval("ID"),Eval("Heading")) %>'><strong> MORE </strong></a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-image">
               <img alt="image" class="img-responsive center-block" src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <% } %>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
 protected void rptNewsList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            _repeaterIndex = _repeaterIndex + 1;

            if (e.Item.ItemIndex % 2 == 0)
            {

                _showTop = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                _showTop = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

By now i have tried several thing but it is not working properly `if (_repeaterIndex % 2 == 0)` this is always true or false based on teh total row count as in my case it always show the `13` as i have 13 records if i display for testing `_repeaterIndex` it show the the correct value but in if it always take the final value of `Container.ItemIndex` not the current value

`<h3 class="title-news blog-title newslisttitle"><%# _repeaterIndex%> <%# Eval("Heading") %></h3>`

What is the best way to solve this issue i am facing

Answer (score 1):

Much easier would be to use `Container.ItemIndex` directly instead of using the `ItemDataBound` Event. You can do this by using two PlaceHolders and set their Visibility based on the value of ItemIndex.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 0 %>'>

        Even content<br />

    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Container.ItemIndex % 2 == 1 %>'>

        Odd content<br />

    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I solved this problem using similar solution yesterday rather i am using `rptNewsList_ItemDataBound` to hide and show control, while your way of doing is cool also

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours trying to find other-ways of solving this issue i finally used two Panel and i hide & show based on the `e.Item.ItemIndex % 2 == 0` value in teh code behind. I thing this is the most effective way of doing it.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNewsList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" OnItemDataBound="rptNewsList_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>

     ***HTML WILL GO HERE   

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelTopImage" CssClass="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 no-padding newslist-col">

 </asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelBottomImage" CssClass="col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 no-padding newslist-col">

   ***HTML WILL GO HERE  

</asp:Panel>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void rptNewsList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            Panel pnlTopImage = e.Item.FindControl("PanelTopImage") as Panel;
            Panel pnlBottomImage = e.Item.FindControl("PanelBottomImage") as Panel;

            if (e.Item.ItemIndex % 2 == 0)
            {

                pnlTopImage.Visible = true;
                pnlBottomImage.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pnlTopImage.Visible = false;
                pnlBottomImage.Visible = true;
            }
        }


    }
```